# Can I do some preprocessing on image and use it without save changes?

Tags: django, image, file, opencv

Recently I wrote a code that reads an image from an object storage. Then I do some simple image processing on the image. but I don't want to save changes on the main image, also I don't want to copy image because of performance reasons. I just want to send manipulated image to a vies function in django in order to open it as a data file.

is it any way to do this job?

this is my function's schema.

```
def watermark_image(image_name):

# do some image processing on input image
#    cv2.imwrite(image_name, image)

    return image
```

and this is a part of my function view:

```
    if request.method == 'GET':
         new_image = watermark_image(local_path + object_name)

    #   image_data = open(??? , "rb").read()
        image_data = open(new_image , "rb").read()
        return HttpResponse(image_data, content_type="image/png")
```

i don't know what should to wirte insetead of this line :

```
    image_data = open(new_image , "rb").read()
```

Comment: Look at writing the new image to an in-memory [BytesIO](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#binary-i-o) object

Comment: @lainShelvington

in order to more clearly describing problem, i want to watermark a lot of images, which is stored in an object storage. i get every image and send it to watermark function. at the end i just want to show the result image as a httpresponse. in order to reduce time duration, i don't want to save image which is manipulated in watermark function.

Comment: Is your image is on the disk, or already in the ram? Also you say you don't want to save changes on the main image but in your watermark_image function there is imwrite?

Comment: @unlut currently my image is on my disk but in the future i want to read images from an object storage on the net, and when i get each image from this storage, it will enter to ram. also imwrite is commented and i don't use it actually.